# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

Im facing an error which i spent now hour trying to fix and now im out of ideas and no other threads/questions/answers from existing posts solve the problem

When i start my tests in docker, i get this error message from the selenium.test container:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://selenium-hub:5555/wd/hub/session. The exception message was: Connection refused (selenium-hub:5555)
```

My Dockerfile looks like this now:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 5555

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

#COPY chromedriver /app/
#RUN chmod +x /app/chromedriver

RUN dotnet restore "BitflySelenium/BitflySelenium.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "BitflySelenium/BitflySelenium.csproj" -c Release -o build


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .
#COPY --from=build /app/chromedriver .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "build/BitflySelenium.dll"]
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "5555:5555"
    expose:
      - "5555"
    networks:
       - hub_network

  chrome-node:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=5555
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    networks:
       - hub_network

  selenium.test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: BitflySelenium/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
      - chrome-node
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    networks:
       - hub_network

networks:
 hub_network:
  external: false
```

And the code which creates the ChromeDriver looks like this:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    SeleniumUtils = new SeleniumUtils(Device);
    SetupTest();
}

public class SeleniumUtils
{
    private const int MaxWait = 15; // seconds
    private ChromeDriverService _pId = null!;
    private readonly IWebDriver _webDriver;
    public SeleniumActionUtils ActionUtils { get; }

    public SeleniumUtils(string? device)
    {
        _webDriver = CreateWebDriver(device);
       // if (_webDriver is RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver) remoteWebDriver.FileDetector = new LocalFileDetector();

        var webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaxWait));
        ActionUtils = new SeleniumActionUtils(_webDriver, webDriverWait);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates the chromeDriver.
    ///     Before it creates a new driver, it kills all existing chromedriver.
    ///     This method contains all the paramter for the chrome browser (incognito, headless, window size,...)
    /// </summary>
    private IWebDriver CreateWebDriver(string? device)
    {
        // Kill running Chromium proesses
        _pId = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        _pId.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        KillProcess();

        var options = ChromeOptions(device);
        //IWebDriver webDriver;


        var  webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://selenium-hub:5555/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities());
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

       // webDriver = new ChromeDriver(_pId, options);
        
        
        return webDriver;
    }

    private static ChromeOptions ChromeOptions(string? device)
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new();
        options.AddArguments("--incognito");
        options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.AddArguments("--port=5555");
        options.AddArguments("--remote-debugging-port=5555");
        options.AddArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
        options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.AddArguments("--lang=en");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
        options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Downloads");

        var currentHeadlessStatus = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HEADLESS_MODE");
        if (currentHeadlessStatus == "true")
        {
            options.AddArguments("--headless=new");
            options.AddArguments("--headless=chrome");
        }

        var deviceSettings = new ChromiumMobileEmulationDeviceSettings();
        switch (device)
        {
            case null:
            case "desktop":
                deviceSettings.Width = 1920;
                deviceSettings.Height = 1080;
                break;
            case "mobile":
                deviceSettings.Width = 390;
                deviceSettings.Height = 844;
                deviceSettings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36.";
                options.EnableMobileEmulation(deviceSettings);
                break;
            case "tablet":
                deviceSettings.Width = 768;
                deviceSettings.Height = 1024;
                deviceSettings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36.";
                options.EnableMobileEmulation(deviceSettings);
                break;
        }

        return options;
    }
```

I simply cant get it to run. I changed the ports from 4444 to 5555 just to see if the port 4444 is blocked. But this also didnt really solve the problem.

I appreciate any hint what i could do to fix that problem! Thanks!